# Not being able to have two QComboBox with the same item

Tags: python, pyqt, qcombobox

I have a list that contains all the drivers from a F1 season:

```
drivers = ['ALO', 'BOT', 'GAS', 'GIO', 'HAM', 'KUB', 'LAT', 'LEC', 'MAZ', 'NOR', 'OCO', 'PER', 'RAI', 'RIC', 'RUS', 'SAI', 'MSC', 'STR', 'TSU', 'VER', 'VET']
```

And two QComboBox that I load with that list

```
self.comboDrivers_1.addItems(drivers)
self.comboDrivers_2.addItems(drivers)
```

I want the QComboBox not to contain the item that the other one has.
Maybe is there a way to hide temporarily a item, and show again whenever the other QComboBox change its value?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the situation, there are various options available.

For a basic `items[x] -> items[without x]` case (and vice versa), a viable option is to use combined pairs of [QSortFilterProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html).

The background is to create a basic source model containing all items, and set a QSortFilterProxyModel for each combo that will eventually be *filtered* depending on the other selected index.

The drawback of this approach is that the `currentIndex` of each combo box can *never* be used as a proper one in the items' indexes: if index `0` is hidden, the combo's `index` 0 will be the second one. This *must* be considered for all signals that use the combo index as argument, including `currentIndexChanged`.
That said, you can still get the [`currentText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#currentText-prop) of the selected combo.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

Drivers = [
    'ALO', 'BOT', 'GAS', 'GIO', 
    'HAM', 'KUB', 'LAT', 'LEC', 
    'MAZ', 'NOR', 'OCO', 'PER', 
    'RAI', 'RIC', 'RUS', 'SAI', 
    'MSC', 'STR', 'TSU', 'VER', 'VET'
]

DriverRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1


class ProxyDriverModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    ignoreIndex = -1
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setSourceModel(QtCore.QStringListModel(Drivers))

    def setIgnoreIndex(self, index):
        if self.ignoreIndex != index:
            self.ignoreIndex = index
            self.invalidateFilter()

    def data(self, index, role=DriverRole):
        if role == DriverRole:
            # return the original index for the row based on the source data
            return self.mapToSource(index).row()
        return super().data(index, role)

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
        # ignore the *source* row if it matches the ignoreIndex
        return row != self.ignoreIndex


class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.comboDrivers_1 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.comboDrivers_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.comboDrivers_1)
        layout.addWidget(self.comboDrivers_2)

        self.comboModel1 = ProxyDriverModel()
        self.comboModel2 = ProxyDriverModel()
        self.comboDrivers_1.setModel(self.comboModel1)
        self.comboDrivers_2.setModel(self.comboModel2)

        self.comboDrivers_1.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updateCombo1)
        self.comboDrivers_2.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updateCombo2)

        # ensure we "reset" the combo index to an invalid one for the filtered
        # model that is used on the combo
        # (note: this MUST be done AFTER connecting signals of both combos)
        self.comboDrivers_1.setCurrentIndex(-1)
        # set the current index to the wanted one
        self.comboDrivers_1.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def updateCombo1(self, index):
        driverIndex = self.comboDrivers_1.itemData(index, DriverRole)
        self.comboModel2.setIgnoreIndex(driverIndex)

    def updateCombo2(self, index):
        driverIndex = self.comboDrivers_2.itemData(index, DriverRole)
        self.comboModel1.setIgnoreIndex(driverIndex)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
test = Test()
test.show()
app.exec()
```